# iOS, Firebase - Firebase causing crash - How to unconfigure app so that I can use database?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I configured my app using

```
FirebaseApp.configure();
```

In my Appdelegate and launched the app.

I then needed to add database functionality so I removed the above code (because it crashes and tells me the app is already configured) and added:

```
AppDelegate.ref = Database.database().reference()
```

But then I get this error:

```
must call `[FIRApp configure]` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) before using Firebase Database.'
```

So, I am now stuck because if I add the `configure()` back my app just crashes and the error tells me the app is already configured.

Do I have to reconfigure? If so, how do I go about doing that as there is nothing in the documentation on this?

Comment: This type of crash usually happens when there’s something wrong with the configuration file that I think you have added after downloading it from the Firebase console. You don’t have to remove FirebaseApp.configure() from AppDelegate. Check if everything is ok with your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Francesco, [I redownloaded the configuration file.](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?authuser=0) This fixed the issue.